# Zend_Controller_Router_Route: Could not find a translator

Tags: zend-framework, multilingual, zend-controller-router

I am developing a multilanguage application. In the bootstrap there is the routes setup:

```
protected function _initRoutes() {

    $this->bootstrap('frontController');
    $router = $this->frontController->getRouter();

    // PAGES ROUTE
    $page = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        ':language/:ident',
        array(
            'module'  => 'core',
      'controller' => 'pagine',
      'action'  => 'view'             
        ),
        array(
            'ident' => '[a-zA-Z-_0-9]{3,}',
         'language' => '[a-z]{2}'
        )
    );

    $registrazione = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        ':language/@utenti/@registrati',
        array(
            'module'  => 'core',
'controller' => 'utenti',
'action'  => 'registrazione'
        ),
        array(
         'language' => '[a-z]{2}'
        )
    );

    $router->addRoute('page', $page);
    $router->addRoute('registrazione', $registrazione);

    .....
```

}

I cannot set the default translator to Zend_Controller_Router_Route (for translated segments) because i don't know the language parameter in the request object.
I get the language parameter in Multilanguage Plugin during the "routeShutdown":

```
class Activa_Controller_Plugin_Multilanguage extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {

public function routeShutdown(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {
    $language = $request->getParam("language");
    $locale   = new Zend_Locale($language);

    $translate = new Zend_Translate('array', APPLICATION_PATH.'/config/lang/'.$language.'.php', $locale);

    Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Locale', $locale);
    Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Translate', $translate);

    Zend_Controller_Router_Route::setDefaultTranslator($translate);
    ////////////////////////
    // BUT NOW IS TOO LATE
    ////////////////////////
}
```

When i type the address "http://servername/it/utenti/registrati" i get the exception with the message "Could not find a translator".

How can i fix it?
Antonio (Italy)

Comment: what about changing when your plugin fires. So instead of routeShutdown you do routeStartup.

Answer (score 1):

Create a routeStartup() plugin, in which you scan the request URI for the locale/language, for example with a simple Regex. Then create and set the default translator in the Router.